# Python While Loop infinite

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, infinite-loop

i'm doing a game where a user gets a random number after rolling a dice, and they play with a bot. The game should exit after 4 rounds, but instead it carries on. If anyone knows how to stop it from looping over and over again, i'd appreciate it.

```
import sys
import random
import time

rounds=0

def user1bot(rounds):
    print("")
    input("Enter A to roll the Dice!")
    userscore=random.randint(1,6)
    print("You Scored: "+str(userscore))
    rounds=rounds+1
    print(rounds)
    userbot(rounds)

def userbot(rounds):
    print("Bot is rolling a dice...")
    time.sleep(3)
    userscorebot=random.randint(1,6)
    print("Bot Scored: "+str(userscorebot))
    rounds=rounds+1
    print(rounds)
    user1bot(rounds)

while rounds<5:
    user1bot(rounds)
    continue
else:
    sys.exit()
```

break

Comment: your problem is that userbot1 calls userbot and even thought you are incrementing round the the while rounds < 5 condition never gets checked again becuase the functions keep calling each other

Comment: You are using indirect recursion. You do not need a while loop. Just use an if else inside your functions as to whethe to continue playing or stop. Who starts the game? Bot or user?

Comment: @Onyambu that would be an elegant solution! I think it could be a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using the recursion you wrote, while trying to reduce code repetition, you could do something like:

```
import sys
import random
import time

rounds = 0

def score(user):
    userscore = random.randint(1,6)
    print(f"{user} Scored: {userscore}")
    global rounds
    rounds += 1
    print(rounds)

def user1bot():
    if rounds >= 5: 
        return None
    input("Enter A to roll the Dice! ")
    score('You')
    userbot()

def userbot():
    print("Bot is rolling a dice...")
    time.sleep(3)
    score('Bot')
    user1bot()

user1bot()
```

Answer (score 0):

As Adi commented, the issue is that because once you call user1bot() you never actually return to your while loop, the condition of the while loop is never checked, so your code runs forever. Here is a modified version of your code that I tested - it runs six "rounds," but you could modify it a bit if you really want it to stop after 5 "rounds."

```
import sys
import random
import time

rounds=0

def user1bot(rounds):
    print("")
    input("Enter A to roll the Dice!")
    userscore=random.randint(1,6)
    print("You Scored: "+str(userscore))
    #rounds=rounds+1
    #print(rounds)
    #userbot(rounds)

def userbot(rounds):
    print("Bot is rolling a dice...")
    time.sleep(3)
    userscorebot=random.randint(1,6)
    print("Bot Scored: "+str(userscorebot))
    #rounds=rounds+1
    #print(rounds)
    #user1bot(rounds)

while rounds<5:
    user1bot(rounds)
    rounds += 1
    print(rounds)
    userbot(rounds)
    rounds += 1
    print(rounds)
    #continue this is unnecessary
else:
    sys.exit()
```

I wrote it this way to conform to the way that you increment rounds in your original code. I think it would make more sense, however, to count a round as being every time both the user and the bot have finished rolling. To implement it this way, I would change the while loop like this:

```
while rounds<5:
    user1bot(rounds)
    userbot(rounds)
    rounds += 1
    print(rounds)
```